# Is it possible to have both a stateful widgets and a stateless widget as subtypes of another class?

Tags: flutter, polymorphism

I recently tried to create an abstract widget, that has then both a stateless and a stateful implementation, which both can be accessed via factory-methods.

Below I added a minimal example of the only real working solution I have figured out that works for my use case, but it leaves me with some things to be desired.

For example with this solution, I have to declare and override every variable in the sub-classes, while I would really like to rely on the fact that they are subtypes and implicitly have those variables.

Has anyone of you ever needed to do a similar thing? Have you worked out a different approach?

For those concerned about as to why I would need this: I wanted to make a singular Button-Class for my App, that then has different implementations for specific styles of buttons (regular button, a 'striped' button, a button that 'loads' as the user scrolls down a page and becomes active once the user reached the end of the page, etc.). That way I could then simply call 'Button.implementation' wherever i needed a specific button, and have all the button-related Code in the same place.

Cheers.

```
abstract class A {
  final int intellect;

  A(this.intellect);

  factory A.giveMeB(int intellect) {
    return _B(intellect);
  }

  factory A.giveMeC(int intellect) {
    return _C(intellect);
  }
}

class _B extends StatelessWidget implements A {
  @override
  final int intellect;

  _B(this.intellect);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox.shrink();
  }
}

class _C extends StatefulWidget implements A {
  @override
  final int intellect;

  const _C(this.intellect, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CState createState() => _CState();
}

class _CState extends State<_C> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```